# Formula to use File path stored in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a Cell A1 on a sheet named 'Settings' with the following file path:

```
C:\Users\Arun Victor\Documents\New folder\MASTER.xlsm
```

Sheet1 on the same Workbook has a bunch of cells linked to various cells in MASTER.xlsm like the one shown below:

```
='C:\Users\Arun Victor\Documents\New folder\[MASTER.xlsm]Employee WOs'!D4
```

Right now,Whenever there is a change in file path I have to manually edit each and every cell. Instead, I need a formula that uses the File path stored in the common cell A1 and does an operation like this:

```
='*File path from Sheet-Settings A1* Employee WOs'!D4
```

Comment: Might sound a little simplistic, but I find the cleanest way to do this is just to do a find and replace on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Indirect()`.  If your cell A1 has the path that you will change (`C:\Users\Arun Victor\Documents\New folder\[MASTER.xlsm]`).

In your sheet1, those cells which are currently `=C:\Users\Arun Victor\Documents\New folder\[MASTER.xlsm]Employee WOs'!D4`, can be replaced with `=Indirect("'"&A1&"Employee WOs'!D4")`.

Here's an example.  I have a Workbook called "TextBook.xlsx" on my desktop.  I want my formula to return the value of whatever cell I want, which I will put in cell C9.

[image]

I can change C9 from `A1` to `B1029` for instance, and D9 will return whatever value that cell has. (in my 'TextBook.xlsx', `A1` literally just says "Cell A1".

**Note** about using `Indirect()`, you must have the file you're using open, or else you'll get an error.  In other words, I have my TextBook.xlsx open, which is why you can see the result ("Cell A1").  If I close the workbook, that will change to a `#REF` error.

Comment: A1 os not on Sheet1, its in a different sheet called Settings. Will ` =Indirect("'"&A1&"Employee WOs'!D4") ` work?

Comment: Haha, sorry, which "A1"? My example A1 (in cell `C9`) is on my example Sheet1.  If it's in "Settings", then just change the text in `B9` (in my example) to "Settings" instead.  If I understand correctly, the PATH (which will change) is in `Summary!A1`, and your formulas using that PATH are in `Sheet1` (or some non-"Summary" sheet).  If so, then in your `indirect()` statement, just make sure the sheet being referred to is `Summary` (either by typing it in the formula where `&B9&` is (replace `B9` with `"Summary"`), or change "sheet1" in my example cell `C9` to `Summary`.

Answer (score 0):

In your VBA code, you can use something like:

```
= Sheet("Settings").Cells(1,1) & "Employee WOs'!D4"
```

This way your code will automatically take your changes on cell A1 from your Settings sheet.